# Facing item width issue while arranging multiple items in a div

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have to display some item card. Each card has `min-width` property. When my screen size change, card size also changed. Because of that, I am facing a problem. That is, the last item/items takes whole area. Is it possible to keep a minimum width for each card, though it is last item or not? Please help.

Problem: [image]

Attempt: [image]

Please find in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-items-arrange-926fx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you also want to specify a `max-width` for your cards.
In your example it could simply be:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #f5fbfd;
  position: relative;
  &:hover ${Info} {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;
```

You can of course also leave `max-width: 280px` if you don't wish to change the width of the elements at all.

Additionally you can add `justify-content: flex-start` to the container to make it look less weird on resizes. In your example:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
`;
```